# Jquery Show Hide Function Not showing image

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code and all has been fine until I tried to add a class within the div menu ID. The image that the class contains becomes invisible when i add the class and I know it has something to do with the current Jquery code but I can't quite find the solution.

Original working HTML code:

```
<div id="menu_container">  
    <div id="menu_CyclopeanCity">
        <h2>A Cyclopean City of No Architecture</h2>
        <a href="images/recent/1.jpg" rel="lightbox [1]" title="A Cyclopean City of No Architecture">
            <span class="roll"></span>
            <img src="images/recent/1.jpg" class="slider"  />
        </a>
        <p>A Cyclopean City of No Architecture Known to Man is a vertical heavily-textured painting on canvas-board that incorporates found objects, collage, 
                crack-filler, and oil paint. The composition is simple, consisting of a gradient background, a rough pyramidal shape in the middle-ground, and a framed 
                photograph in the foreground. The texture on the pyramid and photographic frame is built up of heavily applied with a type of durable, all-purpose 
                crack-filler. 
        </p>
        <br><br>
        <p><strong id="price">Price:</strong><span class="bullets">R11 650</span></p>
        <p><strong>Painting Status:</strong><span class="bullets">Available</span></p>
        <p><strong id="date-painted">Date Painted:</strong><span class="bullets">2013</span></p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Original JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_container div:first-child").show();
    $("#nav a").click(function(){
        var id =  $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.split('_');
        $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
        $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Here's a working JS fiddle with the div class added as a parent class over the image which is now not appearing because of the class - http://jsfiddle.net/9cAV3/

Comment: In your css on the fiddle you have `#menu_container div` set to display none. This will hide the div so you don't see the image. See http://jsfiddle.net/9cAV3/1/ with the css removed

Comment: This hides the #menu_container div until a nav link is clicked...

Comment: Yes but you never show it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
$("#menu_container > div").hide();
```

Instead of

```
$("#menu_container div").hide();
```

Same thing for the css

```
#menu_container > div {
    display:none;
}
```

This will hide the immediate div inside of menu_container which will target `<div id="menu_CyclopeanCity">`. This way your .parent div won't be hidden.

You could also add a class for the container div so you target the divs directly

```
$("#menu_container").find('.container_div').hide();
```

By doing this it is a bit faster comparing to the > div